# Preg_Match Last String From A URL

Tags: php, preg-match

What i'm trying to do is to get the pagination from a web url with preg_match

Example: http://www.google.com/page/223

What i need from this url is " 223 "

I try this code but is not working ...

```
preg_match('~"http://www.google.com/page/(.*)"~iU', 'http://www.google.com/page/223', $page);

print_r($page);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using the `"` in the pattern? There are not quotes in the string. Also the `U` is wrong.

It should be:

```
preg_match('~http://www.google.com/page/(.*)~', 'http://www.google.com/page/223', $matches);
echo $page = $matches[1];
```

Comment: Please also review my post. A regex might not be needed (though this works fine)

Answer (score 2):

**First way**

```
preg_match("/[^\/]+$/", "http://www.google.com/page/223", $matches);
$last_word = $matches[0]; // 223
```

**Second way**

```
substr(strrchr(rtrim($url, '/'), '/'), 1)
```

**Third way**

```
$ex = explode("/",$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
      echo end($ex);
```

Comment: Good alternatives. I mostly like the explode attempt. +1

Answer (score 1):

No need for regex or exploding, just use a string function:

```
$url = "http://www.google.com/page/223";
$lastPart = substr($url, strrpos($url, "/")+1); // +1 to move 1 past the /
```

If you want it more secure (e.g. '/page/' has to exists):

```
$url = "http://www.google.com/page/223";
$lastPart = substr($url, strrpos($url, "/page/")+6); // +6 to move 1 past the '/page/'
if($lastPart===false){ $lastPart = 0; echo "Not found";}
```

Always try to use string functions instead of regex/array functions, string functions are a lot faster.